# rsync keeps disconnecting: broken pipe

Tags: ssh, networking, rsync, backup

I'm using `rsync` to backup my home directory. This has been working fine for a long time now. Here's the command I'm using:

```
rsync \
    -pavz \
    --delete \
    --exclude 'mnt/' \
    --exclude '.cache/' \
    --exclude 'Videos/' \
    --exclude 'Music/' \
    --exclude 'Documents/virtualbox' \
    /home/"${USER}" "${server}":"${dir}" 2>> "${errorFile}"
```

However, I switched the server to which I'm backing up and now `rsync` starts and runs for a few seconds (up to a few minutes), but then stops with the error message

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x: Broken pipe
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(820) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Since it is working on other servers, I suspect that the problem is either the connection or the server itself. The connection seems to be stable. I'm connected via cable and I don't see any interruptions. I also tried pinging the server while doing the backup. The ping has a response rate of 100 % even when the backup is breaking up.

I use `kerberos` to authenticate on the remote server.

I tried several combinations with `ServerAliveInterval`, `ServerAliveCountMax` or `ClientAliveInterval` in my `~/.ssh/config`, but to no avail.

It could be that there is something running on the server that kills the `rsync` command for some reason, but I don't know how to investigate in that. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I should add that I use `kerberos` to authenticate on the remote server.

Comment: That's potentially very important. Please [edit] your question to include this information

Comment: On this server, does the call to rsync fail every single time, or only sometimes? Also, if repeatedly measuring the time it takes to fail, do any patterns appear? I'm thinking about Kerberos authentication timing out, or something similar.

Comment: seeing an io error makes me wonder if the remote side's filesystem filled up?

Comment: @dhag `rsync` fails every time after a few minutes. So if the syncing takes less time than that, it wouldn't fail. I don't see any pattern in the time when it stops. Kerberos authentication cannot be the issue, since I can still logon the machine without reinvoking kerberos. If I'm connected to the machine, I never disconnect.

Comment: @JeffSchaller The file system is not filled up, there is plenty of space left.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but I have to ask simply to rule out the obvious -- are both servers on a wired Ethernet connection, or is one of them using WiFi?

Comment: @rubynorails Both are wired.

Comment: I know you are looking for an `rsync` answer, but have you tried `scp`?  If so, did you encounter any difficulties using it instead of `rsync`?  I know `rsync` is preferable in most cases such as yours, but using `scp` may help narrow down the issues you are encountering.

Comment: @rubynorails Interesting. That seems to work without problems.

Comment: @pfnuesel see my updated answer.  It may not provide a solution to the root cause of your issue, but it should be able to provide an adequate workaround and some troubleshooting wiggle room in the meantime if you need to take awhile to figure it out.

Comment: @pfnuesel, did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @tim.rohrer No, it still persists.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem might be (lack of) memory. Back when 1GB was big for a server, rsync would fail on me for large datasets. Perhaps the algorithm has improved of the memory capacities has increased, but I haven't seen that problem in 8 years or so. So really, this is an outside shot, but one worth exploring. Try smaller datasets first. You might also try  -- as a form on sanity check -- doing a tar-tar:

```
tar cf - $HOME | ssh ${server} tar xf -
```

If that *also* fails after a few minutes, it's not memory.

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered this with `rsync` in the past as well.  The solution that fixed it for me was running it from within a `screen` session, which was able to help maintain the connection to the remote server.

```
screen -LS rsync
[execute your rsync command]
Ctrl-A+D to detach from the session
```

You can check the status by running `screen -x rsync` (or whatever you decide to name the session if you do give it a name, which is not required).  This will re-attach your current shell to that session.  Just remember to detach from it again after you have checked the status so that it keeps running in the background.

You can also execute the command to run via `screen` in the background in one fail swoop by doing [someone please correct me if I'm wrong] `screen -dm 'command'`.  You may want to `man screen` before trying that last one.

**EDIT:**

*I am editing my answer because you have confirmed that `screen` provides no assistance in this scenario, but you replied to my comment suggesting to try `scp` and see what kind of results you get, to which you replied that oddly enough, it worked just fine.*

**So my new answer is this:  *use `scp` -- or `ssh` (with `tar`) -- instead of `rsync`***

Granted, `scp` doesn't support the vast number of features as `rsync`, but you'd actually be surprised to discover just how many features that it *does* support that are almost *identical* to that of `rsync`.

**Real world scenarios for `scp` and other alternatives to `rsync`:**

Awhile back, I was tasked with creating a shell script that would pull logs from our production servers and store them locally on a web server so that developers could access them for troubleshooting purposes.  After trying unsuccessfully to get the Unix team to install `rsync` on our servers, I came up with a workaround using `scp` that worked just as well.

That being said, I recently modified the script so that all it uses is `ssh` and `tar` -- `GNU tar`/`gtar`, to be exact.  GNU `tar` supports many of the options that you will actually find in `rsync`, such as `--include`, `--exclude`, permission/attribute preservation, compression, etc.

The way I now accomplish this is by `ssh`-ing to the remote server (via pubkey auth) and using `gtar -czf - [other options such as --include='*.log' and --exclude='*core*', etc.]` -- this writes all of the info to `stdout`, which is then piped [locally] to `tar -xzf` so that no changes are made on the remote production server, and all of the files pulled as-is to the local server.  It's a great alternative to `rsync` in this case.  The only thing important thing neither `tar` nor `scp` support are incremental backups and the level of block-level error checking that `rsync` features.

The full command I am referring to when using `ssh` and `tar` would be something like this (remote is Solaris 10; local is Debian, for what it's worth):

```
cd /var/www/remotelogs
ssh -C user@remotehost "cd /path/to/remote/app.directories; gtar -czf - --include='*.log' --exclude='*.pid' --exlude='*core*' *" | tar -xz
```

*In your scenario it would be the opposite -- `tar -cf -` locally, and pipe to remote server via `ssh user@remotehost "tar -xf -"` -- there is another answer that references this type of behavior but doesn't go into as much detail.*

There are a few other options that I have included to speed things up.  I timed everything relentlessly to get the execution time as low as possible.  You would think that using compression with `tar` would be pointless, but it actually speeds things up a bit, as does using the `-C` flag with `ssh` to enable `ssh` compression as well.  I may update this post at a later date to include the exact command that I use (which is very similar to what I posted), but I don't feel like getting on VPN at the moment since I'm on vacation this week.

On Solaris 10, I also use `-c blowfish`, because it is the quickest cipher to authenticate with and also helps speed things up a tad, but our Solaris 11 either don't support it or have this cipher suite disabled.

Additionally, if you choose to go with the `ssh`/`tar` option, it would actually be a good idea to implement my original solution of using `screen` if you are doing a backup that will take awhile.  If not, make sure your keepalive/timeout settings in your `ssh_config` are tweaked just right, or this method will also be very likely to cause a broken pipe.

Even if you go with `scp`, I always find it to be a best practice to use `screen` or `tmux` when doing an operation of this sort, *just in case*.  Many times I don't follow my own advise and fail to do this, but it is indeed a good practice to use one of these tools to ensure that the remote job doesn't screw up because of your active shell session getting disconnected somehow.

**I know you want to figure out the root cause of your `rsync` issue.  However, if this is really important, these are two great workarounds that you can experiment with in the meantime.**

Comment: I tried it with `screen`, the outcome is the same.

Comment: @pfnuesel - at least it's good to know that you can rule it out.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem on OSX El Capitan and fixed this by upgrading to rsync v3.11. 
The issue was happening for me on v2.6.9.

Comment: I'm running `rsync 3.1.1`.

Comment: You may want to check your router doesn't have packet flooding protection (or any similar protection) enabled. Are you connecting through any sort of VPN?

Comment: That might be the problem. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the network devices. It works fine on other servers, though, so I'm guessing that this particular server has some sort of packet flooding protection.

Answer (score 2):

Kerberos is only for authentication, that should not cause any problems after you have created a successful connection.

Have you tried using the rsync daemon too?

Are your servers on the same network or do you have a firewall/router between?

You could try setup a netcat session between the servers, that is a simple way to try if you have any connection problems between your servers.

On the first server:

```
nc -lk <port-number>
```

And on the client

```
nc <server> <port-number>
```

You could leave the connection open, and see if the connection keep it, or if you loose the connection. You can also try write something on the client, see that it ends up on the other side.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have root access on the server. This means I cannot run an rsync daemon or a netcat session.

Comment: @pfnusel you can run `netcat` on any port >1024 without needing root privileges

Answer (score 1):

You have something on the remote server that writes to *stdout*. This might be in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`. It could be something less obvious like `stty` or `mesg`. If in doubt, copy a transcript into your question of you logging in to the server (redact the hostname by all means).

Comment: I don't understand. Neither what's going wrong, nor what I'm supposed to do to find out what's writing on stdout.

Comment: @pfnuesel if you copy the transcript of you logging in and post it here, someone may see what's up. Better, post your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` for review. You're looking for things like `mesg` or `stty`

Comment: There's no `mesg` or `stty` in any of my dotfiles.

Comment: @pfnuesel anything else that writes to the terminal during login?

Comment: No, but even if I add something that writes to stdout. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: @pfnuesel f you had added something writing to _stdout_ it would have definitely broken `rsync` over `ssh`. That it didn't break it any differently suggests to me that this could be a reason. Can you pastebin your `.bash_profile` or `.profile`? Or a typescript (`script`) of the login process to the remote server?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. I added an `echo` statement to `.bash_profile`. It didn't change anything. `rsync` was running fine for a few minutes, before crashing. Now I deleted `.bash_profile` and `.profile`. Same thing, it crashes after a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

the only time I've had a problem like this with rsync, I tracked it down to a spare ethernet port on another machine that had the same IP address as my target server.  If rsync is flaky, it is almost surely a network reliability or (in my case) configuration problem.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem when running `rsync` or manually (either with `cp`, `scp` or in Gnome Nautilus) copying large files from a Linux desktop to a low powered ARM based Linux NAS over a gigabit cabled network (no `kerberos` in my setup). The NAS drives are shared using `samba`, and are mounted on the client using `cifs`. The solution for me was to mount the NAS file system from the client without any caching (see also [mount.cifs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) man pages):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server.lan/somedir /mnt/somedir/ -o cache=none
```

Alternatively, when mounting the NAS drive on the client using `gvfs` in `nautilus` this problem would not persist when copying large files (but that does not work in combination with `rsync` though).

[Make Linux write to network filesystem concurrently with local disk reads](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331184/make-linux-write-to-network-filesystem-concurrently-with-local-disk-reads) elaborates further upon why this problem might be occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade your rsync versions to ensure they are *exactly the same* on both the sending and receiving PCs. See my answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/883487/unable-to-rsync-due-to-broken-pipe/988794#988794.

Comment: Why the downvote? This should be a comment not an answer, maybe? Anyone? Anyone?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem anymore, since I don't have access to that server anymore. But it's a reasonable answer and doesn't deserve the downvote.