# multi-hop rsync through ssh+netcat fails very quickly: connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: rsync, netcat

I want to rsync a directory from a server to my client.  I cannot access the server directly, but need to hop through an ssh gateway.  From my '.ssh/config':

```
Host gw
    User ab123456
    HostName gw.somewhere.ac.uk
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
    ServerAliveInterval 60

Host remote
    User me
    HostName remote.somewhere.ac.uk
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
    ProxyCommand nohup ssh gw netcat -w1 %h %p
    ServerAliveInterval 60
```

It works fine for interactive `ssh` sessions, but `rsync` fails.  Sometimes immediately, sometimes after a few seconds, always before copying any files:

```
$ rsync -av remote:/path/to/somewhere/ somewhere/
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.0]

$ rsync -av remote:/path/to/somewhere/ somewhere/
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout

            Access to this system is monitored etc. etc.

receiving incremental file list
Write failed: Broken pipe
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (12288 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [receiver=3.1.0]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (16336 bytes received so far) [generator]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [generator=3.1.0]
```

I suppose this problem is related to the `netcat` gateway through machine `gw`.  How can I use rsync correctly when I need to use a multi-hop connection?

I'm using netcat because my colleague gave me this configuration file, and it works for normal ssh.

Note that unlike the situation in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/242898/15654), I experience the same problem when I replace `rsync -av` with `scp -pr` (and I do need `rsync`s ability to synchronise properly).

Answer (score 1):

I could get it to work by replacing

```
#ProxyCommand nohup ssh gw netcat -w1 %h %p
```

with

```
ProxyCommand nohup ssh gw -W %h:%p
```

which works for modern OpenSSH.  Now I'm not getting an immediate timeout.